# Как сохранить текстовый файл в нужной кодировке?

Tags: c#, кодировка, unicode, ascii

Как известно строки в С# все в Unicode.
Как сохранить текстовый файл в нужной кодировке ?

Вот такой пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
    string[] str = { "первая строка", "вторая строка", "последняя строка" };
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        foreach (string row in str)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Создает файл, но с кодировкой проблемы, она точно не ASCII.
Первая мысль, нужно строки преобразовать в ASCII перед записью. отлично, беру пример с MSDN, получается так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
    string[] str = { "первая строка", "вторая строка", "последняя строка" };
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        foreach (string row in str)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(UnocodeToASCII(row));
        }
    }
}

private static string UnocodeToASCII(string source)
{

    // Create two different encodings.
    Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
    Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

    // Convert the string into a byte array.
    byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(source);

    // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

    // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
    char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
    ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
    return new string(asciiChars);
}
```

На выходе тоже файл с непонятной кодировкой.
что не я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код сохранения в ASCII работает правильно - он сохраняет русские символы как ?, т.к. в ASCII кодировке русских букв нет. Скоре всего вы хотите сохранить в 1251:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
    string[] str = { "первая строка", "вторая строка", "последняя строка" };
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
    {
        foreach (string row in str)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(row);
        }
    }
}
```

То же самое можно сделать одной строчкой:

```
File.WriteAllLines(file, str, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

---

Перекодировку, так, как вы делаете во втором примере, делать нельзя. Во первых, она пытается прочитать байты строки в Unicode как байты строки в ASCII. Во второых, такой код применим только в случае, если:

- У вас уже битая строка - она была прочитана из байт с указанием неверной кодировки
- Код, который ее читает с неверной кодировкой, исправить нельзя

Во всех остальных случаях нужно просто указывать кодировку в момент преобразования из строки в байты при записи и при обратном чтении.

Comment: спасибо, все понятно.